# Javascript dynamic element Id

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am trying to pass an element through my function and output the id.

Here is what I mean:

```
<input id='password' style="display:inline-block" type="password" name='Password' onKeyDown="setTimeout('validate(this)', 10)" />
```

and the javascript:

```
var validate = function(element)
{
    alert(element.id);        
}
```

Is this the correct way to do the following? All I get is undefined when it alerts. Thank you.

Comment: [You shouldn't use a string as the first argument from `setTimeout()` because it is the same as using `eval`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When called from the `setTimeout` function, the `this` pointer is no longer pointing to the input element, rather it is pointing to the `window` object.

What you can do is

```
onKeyDown="var self=this;setTimeout(function(){validate(self);}, 10)"
```

Or better yet:

```
var validateFn = function(element) {
    return function(){
        alert(element.id);
    };
}
```

and on the element:

```
onKeyDown="setTimeout(validateFn(this), 10)"
```

Comment: Perfect! Ha, I thought I was going crazy.